# Copy files from multiple remote servers using JAVA

Tags: java, networking, server

I need some advice and some suggestions on which approach to follow to create my application.

Objective : 
Copy log files from around 14 to 16 remote servers to a client application, which would be used for monitoring purposes.

I know I can write a Multi-threaded or thread-pooled server-client application in java, but would that be feasible?

Or if there is a way that allows the java client application to log-in to the server and copy files from it all by itself, just as we use 'SCP'. 
(Is it even possible?)

Or if there is a much better of handling such issues.

Which approach would be better and why?

Edit: 
I want to copy files from a remote server, and the question is that whether should I use a client-server socket program to do so, or a library such as JSch?

Comment: Didn't get a question. Just connect to servers via ftp/sftp and download those files. You can do it in parallel of successively - it's up to you and your requirements. Everything is possible with java.

Comment: read the QA and the rules of SO and ask a specific question. have look here also http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-state-of-logging-in-java-2013/

Comment: @Divers ,  I have edited my question, in an attempt to better explain it. 
I have edited my question, in an attempt to better explain it. Yes it is up to me, and both approaches would work successively.

Comment: @firephil , the question is specific, I want some advice on which approach to choose in my case.

Comment: @TahaRushain we don't know your secure, performance or other requirements. How we can answer what would be better in your case?

Comment: @Divers
If 'security' and less complex 'deployment' of software is of concern, than would a solution such ftp/sftp/jscp be more appropriate?

Comment: which application/service writes the logs ? is it written by you or can you modify the source code ? if yes write/collect all logs to one server and download from there as a batch process. If you don't have access or permission to modify the code write a client that connects to all servers one by one and download the logs, better solution, more automated but a lot more work.

Comment: @firephil , I cant change the source code of the logging application, so I think I would have to write a client that connects to those servers one by one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can consider my advise. I once programmed it the other way around. Copying files to one central file server. The program was installed on several servers.

This was implemented with Spring Integration. I've created a message channel with an outbound ftp channel adapter. This setup did the job with little implementation and configuration.

I know Spring Integration for FTP is also using JSCH under the hood.

Comment: I think this approach would be appropriate for me, only that I would copy files to a client computer instead of a centralized server,